# Build project with maven without Neo4j running

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a project set up using spring-data-neo4j. We're trying to have our build process be as lean as possible but I'm not able to build the project unless Neo4j is running.  If it's not running the application context fails to load because it cannot connect to the graph.  We don't have any Neo4j unit tests set up so we could skip loading any Neo4j information entirely but I don't see a way of lazy loading neo4j:repositories and neo4j:config beans.  Is there any way of doing this?  Is there a workaround?

Here's my spring-data-neo4j setup:

```
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.xxx.graph.repository" />
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.xxx.domain" />
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" 
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="${graph.db.url}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to have our unit tests import entirely separate context files.  Now we have a project-context.xml file that imports a project-neo4j.xml file that we for real setup, and a separate project-test-context.xml that we use for our unit tests.  The project-test-context.xml has nothing about neo4j in it.